# How to insert Inf into list without it being coerced to character

Tags: r

I have a list and I want to replace the character string `'Infinity'` with the R numeric value `Inf`. I have tried various approaches but R keeps coercing the value `Inf` to the string `'Inf'`. Here are the approaches I have tried:

```
# Doesn't work
l1 <- list('Infinity')
l1[[1]][l1[[1]] == 'Infinity'] <- Inf
l1
class(l1[[1]])

# Doesn't work
l2 <- list('Infinity')
special.values <- match(l2[[1]], c("Infinity", "-Infinity", "NaN"))
indices <- which(!is.na(special.values))
l2[[1]][indices] <- c(Inf, -Inf, NaN)[na.omit(special.values)]
l2
class(l2[[1]])
```

Unfortunately I have the additional restriction that I can't just do a replace on the entire list because some elements of the list may contain legitimate strings that are `'Infinity'`

```
# This works, but would incorrectly replace data in my use case
l3 <- list('Infinity')
l3 <- replace(l3, l3 == 'Infinity', Inf)
l3
class(l3[[1]])
```

Any ideas on how to make this work. Here is a more complete example of what the code I am actually writing looks like.

```
l4 <- list(1.0, 'Infinity', 'Infinity')
l4.types <- c('numeric', 'numeric', 'character')
for (i in which(l4.types %in% 'numeric')) {
  # insert code here
}
all.equal(l4, list(1.0, Inf, 'Infinity')) # TRUE
```

Comment: For you last example, use `if(l4[[i]] == 'Infinity') l4[[i]] = Inf` for your `#insert code here`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code doesn't work because when you replace *an element* of a character vector, the replacement is coerced to character.

This makes sense in the general case:

```
x = c("a", "b", "c")
x[2] = 1
x
# [1] "a" "1" "c"
```

Vectors must be of one type, so the above is the only way.
It *would not make sense* to have special handling to check if the vector is of length one, thus **we expect this to work the exact same way, and it does**:

```
# this is consistent:
y1 = "infinity"
y1[1] = Inf
y1
# [1] "Inf"
```

If you want to change the class of the vector, you'll either have to replace the whole vector or explicitly coerce it:

```
## replace whole vector (not just an element)
y2 = "infinity"
y2 = Inf
y2
# [1] Inf

## coerce
y3 = "infinity"
y3[1] = Inf
y3 = as.numeric(y3)
y3
# [1] Inf
```

As both of these above methods will also work consistently with longer vectors.

Because of the single bracket replacement in your code highlighted here: `l1[[1]]  [  l1[[1]] == 'Infinity'  ]  <- Inf`, it falls under the `x` and `y1` examples above. The solution is the same, either replace the whole vector or explicitly coerce to numeric. Below I take the "replace the whole vector" approach.

```
l4 <- list(1.0, 'Infinity', 'Infinity')
l4.types <- c('numeric', 'numeric', 'character')
for (i in which(l4.types %in% 'numeric')) {
  if(l4[[i]] == 'Infinity') l4[[i]] = Inf
}
all.equal(l4, list(1.0, Inf, 'Infinity'))
# [1] TRUE
```